# Only one image mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, mouseover

I have one mouseover on my website which is not working. the rest of them work fine. I am using the same codes for each and I am totally baffled why only one doesn't work. Can anyone help? Check my source code here: http://www.alanatashjian.com/gallery_index.html (it's the "gallery" button on the right side that is not mousing over correctly).

or here's the code for the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}
function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
//-->
</script>
```

here's a successful mouseover example:

```
<a href="about.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('button_about','','assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_on_about.gif',1)"><img src="assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_off_about.gif" name="button_about" width="172" height="70" border="0" id="button_about" /></a>
```

and here's my unsuccessful mouseover:

```
<a href="gallery_index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('button_gallery','','assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_on_gallery.gif',1)"><img src="assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_off_gallery.gif" name="button_gallery" width="172" height="73" border="0" id="button_gallery" /></a>
```

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: Yes, I get these: "[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () (messages.json, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The file “messages.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (messages.json, line 0)" in reference to this: "safari-extension://com.evernote.safari.clipper-Q79WDW8YH9/d386d4f6/_locales/en_us/messages.json" …but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello just copy paste this code to your file

```
<a href="gallery_index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('button_gallery1','','assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_on_gallery.gif',1)"><img src="http://www.alanatashjian.com/assets/triceralayoutplantop_button_off_gallery.gif" name="button_gallery" width="172" height="73" border="0" id="button_gallery1"></a>
```

Telling you what was the problem your have two img tags with same id see

> **button_gallery**

its in a gallery and links both so it will not work i just change **button_gallery** to **button_gallery**

If you have same id in two images then it will not work just change gallery anchor tag

Comment: Thank you so much! Upon further inspection you were right, I had 2 id= tags as 'button_gallery' and just needed to change one to 'button_links'. Thank you! I had scoured my code but had failed to notice that one.